# Is there a way to bind a bot to one specific channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot, and want to make it only be able to post on 1 specific channel. I can not make it have a lower role than a regular member, or it will not be able to give them roles.

I have tried an if/else statement based on the channel's ID.

```
case 'start':
if (message.channel === 615842616373805067) {
   //somewhat unimportant command
    return message.member.addRole('615166824849604619'), 
    message.channel.send(` ${message.author} has been given the role.)`, 
    message.delete);
    //unimportant command ends here
} else { 
    console.log('Wrong channel, no role.')
}
```

I expect the bot to only be able to post in this one channel.

Comment: `message.channel` is an Object. So you're comparing an object to an integer (which won't work). Try `if (message.channel.id === <channel id>) { <code here> }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking for the `message.channel` Class, try checking for the `id` property of that class

```
if(message.channel.id != "615842616373805067") return console.log('Wrong channel, no role.');
//rest of your code
```

Make sure to check the [official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) for detailed descriptions of each Class, Method, Property, etc.